# Cleanly stopping a thread in VB.net to avoid double error handling

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I’ve got this issue with stopping a thread cleanly. I’ve tried to simplify it into a more basic version of the code below and I’m wondering if my approach is completely wrong here.

I have Form1 with a bunch of UI elements which need updating as BackgroundCode runs (I run it here so it’s a separate thread and it doesn’t hold up the UI) I then update the UI by invoking a sub

```
(Me.Invoke(Sub()
              something.property=something 
           End Sub))
```

I’m also trying to handle some errors handed to the application by an external file. I’ve used a timer to check for the file and if it exists I grab the contents and pass it to my ErrorHandler. This Writes the Error out to a log file, displays it on screen and then aborts the background worker so that the program doesn’t continue to run. The trouble I’m getting is that by executing BackgroundThread.Abort() that action itself is triggering the ErrorHandler. Is there a way to ask the BackgroundThread to stop cleanly? I want BackgroundThread to trigger the ErrorHandler if something else goes wrong in that code.

I’m wondering about using a global boolean like “ErrorIsRunning” to restrict the ErrorHandler sub so that it can only ever run once, but this is starting to feel more and more hacky and I’m wondering if I’ve gone completely off track here and if there might be a better way to approach the entire thing.

```
Public Class Form1
    
    Dim BackgroundThread As New Thread(AddressOf BackgroundCode)

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
        ‘Hide Error Page
        ErrorPage.Visible = False
        ErrorLabel.Visible = False
        ‘Start Background Code
        BackgroundThread.Start()        
        
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundCode()

        Try
        
            ‘<Background code which runs over a number of minutes>
        
        Catch.ex as Exception
            ErrorHandler(“Error with BackgroundCode: “ + ex.Message)
        End Try
        
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
        
                Dim ErrorFile As String =  “C:\MyErrorFile.Err”
                Dim ErrorContents As String
        
             If File.Exists(ErrorFile) Then

                    Timer.Enabled = False
                    ErrorContents = File.ReadAllText(ErrorFile).Trim()
                    ErrorHandler(ErrorContents)

                End If

        End Sub
    
    Public Sub ErrorHandler(ErrorText As String)


                WriteLog(“ERROR” + ErrorText)
            Me.Invoke(Sub()
                            Me.ErrorPage.Visible = True          
                            Me.ErrorLabel.Text = ErrorText                         
                        End Sub)
            BackgroundThread.Abort()
        End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could this be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Thread.Abort should not be used. It will 'kill' the thread so you don't know in what state that thread was (hence the exception) Have the background thread check a boolean every now and then and end its looping based on that boolean. The thread that now calls Thread.Abort should set the boolean.

Comment: `System.Threading.CancellationToken` / `System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource` are designed for this use.  See `IsCancellationRequested`.  Also see `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, I ended up using a backgroundworker instead of just creating a thread and setting it to run in the background (I'm not entirely sure I understand the difference here) but it did allow me to take advantage of cancellation requests. Although it wasn't quite what I wanted which was to be able to end the thread immediately following the last operation it did mean I could easily put lots of break points into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Never abort threads.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8)

This uses a Task and a ManualResetEvent.  Without seeing the code inside of the background task it is hard to know how many **stop checks** might be needed.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private BackgroundTask As Task
    Private BackgroundTaskRunning As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(True)

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Hide Error Page
        ErrorPage.Visible = False
        ErrorLabel.Visible = False
        'Start Background Code
        BackgroundTask = Task.Run(Sub() BackgroundCode())

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundCode()

        Try
            '<Background code which runs over a number of minutes>

            'put stop checks periodically
            ' e.g.
            If Not BackgroundTaskRunning.WaitOne(0) Then Exit Sub 'stop check

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler("Error with BackgroundCode: " + ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick

        Dim ErrorFile As String = "C:\MyErrorFile.Err"
        Dim ErrorContents As String

        If File.Exists(ErrorFile) Then
            Timer.Enabled = False
            ErrorContents = File.ReadAllText(ErrorFile).Trim()
            ErrorHandler(ErrorContents)
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub ErrorHandler(ErrorText As String)
        WriteLog("ERROR" + ErrorText)
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      Me.ErrorPage.Visible = True
                      Me.ErrorLabel.Text = ErrorText
                  End Sub)
        BackgroundTaskRunning.Reset() 'stop task <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    End Sub
End Class
```